# Sutable Tool For Quality Assurences

Tags: tools, uiautomation

Please Tell Me Most sutable QA Tool for UI Testing

Comment: This is way to broad and will result in opinion based answers. Please give more context, what kind of UI / Application type. Desktop, webbased, mobile. What goals do you want to achieve the UI testing? There is not a single "silver bullet" tool.

Answer (score 3):

A reply equally broad as the question, but that does answer it:

1. Go to https://www.testtoolreview.de
2. Filter tools based on your specific situation
3. Compare the available options on specifications that matter to you
4. Pick a winner

You should research a bit more before asking generic questions like that.